# Transparent control with no mouse/keyboard interaction

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

I want to overlay a transparent image over other controls. This image-control should not capture any mouse or keyboard-events, so that the underlying controls are usable as the image isn't there. I want to be able to switch the behaviour to normal using a Property.

How is this possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate about application of such control? It sounds like you are trying to do sort of *shaders* (after-processing) or *layers* (multi-layered output). But then you want a property to make it a normal image. This is confusing. Imagine a textbox with the focus, what your image should do to it? Hide, but allow to continue input or what?

Comment: You can have a background image for example a panel, and use label as buttons for nicer look. Not sure I understand your question - a transparent image would not be visible. To disable events, just set them to disabled

Comment: This article might help you.
 http://www.bobpowell.net/transcontrols.htm